# How to install android-rss (org.mcsoxford.rss) in Eclipse?

Tags: java, android

I don't understand the tutorial. I tried and searched for some help, but there is no normal tutorial how to install it in Eclipse.

Link: https://github.com/ahorn/android-rss

I did the cmd command but I don't understand the last paragraph of the "Installation" section. What do I need to do with the `.classpath` file?

If someone can explain me how to make it work it will be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every Eclipse project has a `.classpath` file. That allows Eclipse to reference your import to some registered classpath, outside your environment classpath.

Inside your `.classpath` file, you will find the **only** entry like so:

```
<classpathentry kind="src" path="ejbModule"/> <!-- doesn't have to be "ejbModule" -->
```

The `README` from the link provided states that you must change the `path` attribute to "/src/main/java". So your new `src` kind will be:

```
<classpathentry kind="src" path="/src/main/java"/>
```

I hope this helps.